# When a G-Manifold is a Hamiltonian G-manifold

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Let G be a lie group, then When a G-Manifold is a Hamiltonian G-manifold and under which condition a manifold is Hamiltonian G manifold for some lie group G

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a hard question and the answer is not known in general, even for $G = S^1$. The obvious necessary condition for a $G$-action on a *compact* symplectic manifold $(M, \omega)$ to be Hamiltonian is that the action has fixed points. This is because the Hamiltonian function will have critical points on a compact manifold, and these critical points will correspond to fixed points of the corresponding Hamiltonian action.

A well-known theorem of Ono shows that the existence of fixed points is also a sufficient condition in the case of circle actions on symplectic manifolds of "Lefschetz type."

> **Theorem.** (Ono) Let $(M^{2n}, \omega)$ be a compact symplectic manifold such that the map
>   $$\wedge \omega^{n-1}: H^1(M; \Bbb R) \longrightarrow H^{2n-1}(M; \Bbb R)$$
>   is an isomorphism. Then a symplectic $S^1$-action on $(M, \omega)$ is Hamiltonian if and only if it has fixed points.

All Kähler manifolds satisfy the hypothesis of the above theorem, so any symplectic $S^1$-action on a Kähler manifold with fixed points is Hamiltonian. However, McDuff found an example of a $6$-dimensional symplectic manifold (not of Lefschetz type) with a symplectic $S^1$-action possessing a fixed point that is *not* Hamiltonian. So Ono's theorem has no hope of extending to all symplectic manifolds.

An often studied class of symplectic manifolds are the monotone symplectic manifolds. The situation is better for them:

> **Theorem.** Any symplectic $S^1$-action on a monotone symplectic manifold is Hamiltonian.

In the noncompact case, there's an easy general result for exact symplectic manifolds $(M, \omega)$, *i.e.* where $\omega = -d\theta$ for some $1$-form $\theta$. A symplectic $G$-action on such an exact symplectic manifold is called exact if the action preserves the $1$-form $\theta$.

> **Theorem.** Any exact symplectic action of a compact Lie group $G$ on an exact symplectic manifold $(M, -d\theta)$ is Hamiltonian with Hamiltonian function $H_\xi = \iota(X_\xi)\theta$ for $\xi \in \mathfrak{g}$.

Answer (score 3):

It might be useful for interested readers to leave more theorems related to this question. They are all standard results and easy to find in textbooks, and this is why I shall just state them without proofs or references.

To fix notation (there are various conventions in the literature): a symplectic action of $G$ on the symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$ is said to be hamiltonian if the image of the Lie algebra of $G$ by the induced infinitesimal action lies inside the Lie algebra of hamiltonian vector fields of $(M,\omega)$. A moment map for a hamiltonian action is said to be equivariant if it induces a Lie algebra antihomomorphism between the Lie algebra of $G$ and the poisson algebra of functions of $(M,\omega)$.

0- If the first cohomology group of the symplectic manifold is trivial, then any symplectic action is hamiltonian.

1- Any hamiltonian action admits a moment map.

2- If the first Chevalley cohomology group of the Lie algebra of $G$ is trivial, then any symplectic action of $G$ is hamiltonian. If, in addition, the second Chevalley cohomology group of the Lie algebra of $G$ is trivial, then any symplectic action of $G$ is hamiltonian and admits an equivariant moment map.

3- Any symplectic action (the Lie group can be noncompact) on an exact symplectic manifold $(M,\omega=\mathrm{d}\theta)$ preserving $\theta$ is hamiltonian and admits an equivariant moment map.

4- (Gotay and Tuynman) A hamiltonian action of a compact Lie group admits an equivariant moment map (the manifold does not need to be compact).

5- A hamiltonian action on a compact symplectic manifold admits an equivariant moment map.

I am assuming that the manifolds and Lie groups are smooth, Hausdorff, paracompact and connected.